# How to get a list of postgresql indexes that have not been used in any queries recently?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to get a list of the indexes that have not been used by any queries since some arbitrary cutoff time in the past? Or more simply, a list of all indexes along with a timestamp of when each one was last used in the execution of a query?

***What I've tried so far***

I've read the Wall Of Text at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW, but a solution is not obvious (I'm mostly a MySQL user and I find PostgreSQL documentation very unclear, lost in the details).

Comment: [pg_stat_all_indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time of last use is not stored, but you can use the query from [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/) to find all indexes that have never been scanned and server no other purpose either:

```
SELECT s.schemaname,
       s.relname AS tablename,
       s.indexrelname AS indexname,
       pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) AS index_size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_indexes s
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON s.indexrelid = i.indexrelid
WHERE s.idx_scan = 0      -- has never been scanned
  AND 0 <>ALL (i.indkey)  -- no index column is an expression
  AND NOT i.indisunique   -- is not a UNIQUE index
  AND NOT EXISTS          -- does not enforce a constraint
         (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
          WHERE c.conindid = s.indexrelid)
ORDER BY pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) DESC;
```

Indexes can serve other purposes than scanning:

- implement constraints
- make autoanalyze gather statistics on the indexed expression